# What is INFO @wlcfg_80211_attach message while booting?

Tags: boot, wireless

My laptop boot time seems to be delayed by this message. I have a Broadcom internal wlan card installed on the laptop and a desktop without a wireless device. The desktop boots much faster, even though it's older than the laptop.

Comment: It sometimes means that a less than optimal driver is installed for your wireless device. Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: It's Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01) and additionally from sysinfo Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device 0510. I'm using the bcmwl-kernel-source version 6.30.223.141 driver.

Answer (score 1):

I would certainly try the other available driver for your Broadcom. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install -- reinstall linux-firmware
sudo modprobe -r wl
sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

It may take a reboot. Does it boot faster now? Does the wireless work as expected?

Comment: There was a 'not found' message for the second command and a 'fatal' for the third, but after a reboot it's still working. I can't see how it sped up the boot, as there was a different message to fast to read on first attempt.

Comment: Is your wireless working as expected?

Comment: It also seems localized to Trusty, as the wlan message flies by when quiet spalsh is turned off in Saucy. It's not that big of a deal, but I am curious. FYI - this laptop came with W7 and I multiboot with Ubuntu Saucy & Trusty as well as Ubuntu Gnome Trusty.

Comment: Yes - no issues on Saucy or Trusty other than the INFO message during the boot sequence. My old laptop uses an older version of Broadcom with fwcutter. It's a bit weak but the USB dongle works well.

Comment: Is the message the same? dmesg | grep -e wl -e brcm

Comment: Hmm - it appears I need a signing key, which I will attempt to find. [   25.817839] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   25.823454] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   25.877346] INFO @wl_cfg80211_attach : Registered CFG80211 phy
[   26.063470] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4727 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.141 (r415941)

Comment: You appear to still be using bcmwl-kernel-source. Did you not remove and purge it as I suggested?

Comment: I may as well close this discussion. I had a look at my dmsg log in full and this INFO message doesn't seem to me slowing the boot time at all. The only area of hesitation - and it's just three seconds is enabling the swap file. BTW - purging the bcmwl-kernel-source file disables my wifi.

Comment: But doesn't loading brcmsmac enable it again??

Comment: No - it only works from the repository driver. The message is part of dmesg in Saucy as well, but since it didn't display itself during the boot sequence I never had occasion to look at it before.